# c# return value from database using other field

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a Microsoft Access database that I would like to use. I've made the connection and can print a whole field to listbox. But is there a way to search for only one keyword and return another value in the other field?
For example what i'm wanting to create is a basic chatbox sort of thing
where there is two fields in the database

```
+-----------------+----------------------+
| INPUT           |       Response       |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| hi              |  "hey, how are you?" |
| hello           |  "hi"                |
+-----------------+----------------------+
```

If the user inputs *hi*, it searches the database and if the keyword is found then it returns the response field according to the keyword?
I've tried using the reader function in `oleDB` namespace but haven't had any luck.
I honestly don't know where to start for the database side of the chat bot.

Comment: You may have an easier time, using entityframework and CompactSQL database instead of access.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public void ResponseToUser(string userInput)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Your database path";
        using (OleDbConnection databaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            databaseConnection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", databaseConnection))
            {
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                string response = string.Empty;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["Keyword"].ToString().Equals(userInput))
                    {
                        response = reader["Response"].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Ok, I edited my answer to full solution. Not sure if you connected to database this way before, but it's supposed to work.

Comment: Getting an IndexOutOfRangeException was Unhandled error on
  if (reader["Keyword"].ToString().Equals(userInput))

Comment: @Evilk9 I edited my answer, if you did connection to database this way before then you should try looking for your answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx
Create new dataset, after that create DataRowCollection and then implement the solution I gave you..